# .NET Windows Live Messenger Connectivity?

Tags: c#, api, connection, irc, windows-live-messenger

Hey there guys, I'm  working on an IRC bot project, Trying to integrate Windows live into a bot, And have received messages sent to the channel. But the current problem is that the old messenger API that I had no longer works. And the current API i can only find information about addins (complicated for the end user to set up unless I make an installer), Or contact information.

I would like my bot to be stand-alone (no messenger required) and have it log in it self, But I can not find information on the login process anywhere.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A alternative (until the new API becomes available) is to use GTalk with a Jabber library like [Agsxmpp](http://www.ag-software.de/agsxmpp-sdk.html).  I switched over to it because the old messenger API wasn't supported.

Answer (score 0):

You may opt to wait for the Messenger Connect API announced last month:

[Messenger Connect](http://windowsteamblog.com/windows_live/b/windowslive/archive/2010/04/29/messenger-across-the-web.aspx)

Alternatively, the following has some information on how to authenticate:

[Authentication API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb676633.aspx)

Good luck.